# Jquery Chosen - Prevents capture of keypress

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events, jquery-chosen

I have a div (id = div_search_fields) within which I have several jQuery Chosen dropdowns.  Attached to the div I have a keypress capture listener which, if the key pressed is the Enter key, submits the selected stuff by clicking a hidden submit button.

```
$("#div_search_fields").keypress(function(e) {
    if (e.which == 13) {
        $("#hiddenSubmitButton").click();
    }
});
```

For some reason this listener is never called if I have just selected an option in one of the chosen dropdowns.  Within the "div_search_fields" DIV I also have a simple text input box and if I have just entered text there and then press the Enter key, the listener is triggered as expected.

This must be something to do with focus on the Chosen dropdowns but I cannot fathom why?  Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Far I can see Jquery chosen is using e.preventDefault() in keypress event so it is not allowing to execute your code. There should be some function which you can override to achieve your goal or you can get ride of e.preventDefault().

Comment: I only want the Enter keypress to fire a submit if something within the div specified has been changed (there are 2 such divs, each with their own submit button so I have a separate listener on each div listening for the Enter keypress which then clicks the appropriate submit button). If I just have standard html elements (dropdowns, text inputs) it all works fine.  It breaks when I initialise the dropdown boxes using JQuery Chosen.  It doesn't look like you are using JQuery chosen in your example above?

Comment: Yeha you are correct. I haven't used JQuery chosen. I am currently looking at it. Hopefully I could get solution. Currently I can see Jquery chosen is using e.preventDefault() in keypress event so it is not allowing to execute ur code. There should be some function which you can override to achieve your goal.

Comment: Your are right!  It is the keydown_checker function in the Chosen javascript which is capturing my keypress and preventing default.  I commented that line out and all works beautifully!  If you edit your post above to say this, I'll mark it as the correct solution...Thank you.

Comment: Awesome, you got your solution. I just changed my answer. I edited it from my comment to answer.

Answer (score 1):

Two things:

1. If the input in the dropdowns is generated dynamically AFTER the keypress event is bound, the event won't be bound to those elements.
2. IDs should be unique to one element. Use a class instead if you want to bind an action to multiple elements.

Use .on() instead:

```
$(".div_search_fields").on("keypress", function(e) { . . . });
```

Comment: The chosen dropdowns are initialised before the listener is attached to the div.  "div_search_fields" is the unique id on the div containing all the dropdowns.