# keypress events in jquery chosen

Tags: jquery, jquery-chosen

Keypress event is not working in jquery chosen. Below is my code:

```
$(".chzn-select").chosen();
$(".chzn-select").keypress(function () {
    $.ajax({
        url: "populateAirportCodes?fragments="+element.target,
        type: "POST",
        data: JSON.stringify(org),
        contentType: "application/json",
        async: false,
        success: function(data) {
            <** populate the data in chosen **>
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: have you seen http://stackoverflow.com/a/12841539/1684530 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can work around this by binding to the container instead:

```
 $(".chzn-select").chosen().data('chosen').container.bind('keypress', …);
```

However, this [is internal API](https://github.com/harvesthq/chosen/issues/1422) and might change between released. For your convenience, [here’s a jsfiddle with this implemented](http://jsfiddle.net/jfu5z/).

Comment: It worked.. But upon populating the values from the ajax call, for the first time it is okay. But for the second and further keypress, the values are accumulating. same values getting repeating. below is the code.  $.each(data, function(index) {
       $(".chzn-select").append(
         $('<option></option>')
          .val(data[index])
           .html(data[index]));
});$(".chzn-select").trigger("liszt:updated"); ... I think am appending to the options on the next hit also. It there any option to clear the chosen options and append the new values from callback..

Comment: Most likely there is, but I believe your new question is better suited to be asked in a new post. On a side note… are you aware that what you are trying to do has been implemented multiple times already: [one](https://github.com/meltingice/ajax-chosen) and [two](https://github.com/ksykulev/chosen-ajax-addition). If you do this to learn, please post your question to a new post. It’s easier than using this comment box.